# Can't get rid of top padding without universal selector

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I can't get rid of the top padding on the webpage.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="textbox">
        <ul>
            <li>Object 1</li>
            <li>Object 2</li>
            <li>Object 3</li>
            <li>Object 4</li>
            <li>Object 5</li>
            <li>Object 6</li>
            <li>Object 7</li>
            <li>Object 8</li>
            <li>Object 9</li>
            <li>Object 10</li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.textbox {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}


.textbox ul {
    overflow: auto;
}


.textbox li {
    display: inline;
}
```

When I add this into my code, the padding problem disappears, but I prefer not to use the * selector.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

How can I get rid of the top padding without the universal selector? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to use a generic reset. It's likely that your `ul` element still has margin or padding on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your margin 0 to the ul

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also look into http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ it comes in handy

http://jsfiddle.net/8vsd2/

Answer (score 0):

The ul element has the margin, so you just need to remove it as so, this removes it solely for the ul you are targeting.

```
.textbox ul {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```